# How do I run libsvm on linux?

Tags: linux, unix, makefile, libsvm, svm

I'm having trouble installing libsvm, presently im running via a ubuntu virtual machine . When I follow the instructions such that on Unix systems, "type `make' to build the`svm-train' and `svm-predict'programs. Run them without arguments to show the usages of them". This is my following error output: I am rather new to both libsvm and unix systems so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
aaron@aaron-laptop:~$ cd Document
bash: cd: Document: No such file or directory
aaron@aaron-laptop:~$ cd Documents
aaron@aaron-laptop:~/Documents$ libsvm-3.12
libsvm-3.12: command not found
aaron@aaron-laptop:~/Documents$ cd libsvm-3.12
aaron@aaron-laptop:~/Documents/libsvm-3.12$ make
g++ -Wall -Wconversion -O3 -fPIC -c svm.cpp
make: g++: Command not found
make: *** [svm.o] Error 127
aaron@aaron-laptop:~/Documents/libsvm-3.12$
```

Comment: Did you install the `gcc` and `g++` compilers? Are you familiar with the command lines, shells, and utilities like `make`, `grep`, `awk` etc...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your terminal and type these commands in order.

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

If this still doesn't work,

open up your terminal, type in 'g+' (without the quotes) and press the  button multiple times. It will show you if the name of the command g++ has been changed or not. (Sometimes updating your linux changes the name of g++ to g++-3.x (where x is a number).

If this is the case, in your installation instructions, replace every g++ by whatever number you got after pressing the  key.